# Custom search in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to delete the accents when I perform a search.

For example in my array it looks like this:

```
objcts = [
   {code: "123", name: "Timóteo"},
   {code: "685", name: "Timozim"},
   {code: "752", name: "Timirim"},
];
```

The guy researching "timo" or "Timo" or "Timó" it should appear for him the same object that is with code 123 and 685.

In research he should return this to me:

```
objcts = [
   {code: "123", name: "Timóteo"},
   {code: "685", name: "Timozim"},
];
```

I tried to use the source to do this function but I can not do it. Would you like to do this using your plugin?

In this return I need it to give me an array with all objects that satisfy that search.

I know that my question was marked with duplicate, but none of them have the answer that I need, one of them shows how to search in string and another the search, I can not put this two contents in one, my doubt is precisely in this part.

Comment: Timo and Timo are fine, how could thymus?

Comment: Actually a bug in my object I will fix

Comment: It can not distinguish between uppercase, lowercase, and accented letters

Comment: What about adding an aditional "shadow" property replicating the name but, in lowercase, and replacing all accented vouls. Then you can look up by that field forcing the search criteria to lower case.

Comment: you could try converting the search either all to lowercase or uppercase and running a filter to get the data

Comment: @Sunil Lama 
Yes, this is exactly what I need and I do not know how to do it.

Comment: objcts = [
   {code: "123", name: "Timóteo"},
   {code: "685", name: "Timozim"},
   {code: "752", name: "Timirim"},
];

function returnResult(word){
var res = objcts.filter((a) => a.name.toLowerCase().includes(word.toLowerCase()));
    console.log(res);
}
    
returnResult('timo');
returnResult('Timo');
returnResult('Timó');

Comment: I'll test your example but I suspect it works with the accents.